# date is getting subtracted while comparing two dates

Tags: c#

I am facing a problem in my code in which I am comparing today's date with the date in database this is my code. Here `label10.Text` is containing the date from database. Basically I am making a reminder app. If the database date matches with todays date then it should send a reminder email

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(label10.Text);
long t = dt.ToFileTime();
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Today;
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(t);
//DateTime date2 = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt64(label10.Text));
//DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2015,9,16);
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
string relationship;
if (result > 0)
{
    relationship = "is earlier than";
    //SendEmail();               
}
else if (result == 0)
{
    relationship = "is the same time as";
    SendEmail();
    //MessageBox.Show("is same");
}

else
{
    relationship = "is later than";
    SendEmail();
    //MessageBox.Show("is later");
}
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", date1, relationship, date2);
```

Now the problem is when I run the application the date2 gets filled with 29.09.15 whereas label 10 shows 30.09.15. I am not getting why it is happening also i have noticed that "dt" gets filled with 30.09.15 12:00:00 AM where as "date 2" 29.09.15 06:30:00 PM, I don't have any other record in DB which have reminder date set to 29.09.15

Comment: what is the date coming from db?

Comment: What is the point of the `date2` variable when you already have that value in `dt`?

Comment: what does ToFileTime() do?

Comment: yeahhh !! thnks for reply i used dt instead of date 2 directly and it worked   @Nikita db was returnid 30.09.15 on which reminder was set

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if this issue has to with the time difference between local time and UTC time? the database time could be UTC time, while the code behind uses localtime. You could convert all times to either local or universal.

```
// for converting to local time
date1.ToLocalTime();
// converting to utc time
date1.ToUniversalTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the ticks of a date and the filetime. The ticks count from January 1, 1970, the filetime counts from January 1, 1601. You need to change this:

```
long t = dt.ToFileTime();
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(t);
```

to this:

```
long t = dt.Ticks;
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(t);
```

Or more simply:

```
DateTime date2 = dt;
```